# Javascript ES6 fat arrows empty parameter f instead of ()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've noticed that when creating functions in Java Script ES5 you can specify parameters that will not necessarily have to be used, e.g.

```
function foo(uselessParam) {
  // code that will not use uselessParam
}
```

If I'm correct - if I wont use this parameter within my function I can call that function without passing that parameter and "foo" will still run without throwing errors. This gave me idea to use fat arrows in ES6 like this:

```
let foo = f => {
    // code not using f parameter
}
```

"f" in my opinion points that this piece of code is a function in more intuitive way than "()" I like doing so, even that "()" suppose to be used when no parameters are specified.

Here is my question: is there any scenario when using empty parameter instead of no parameters passed at all could be a problem? Could using this pattern cause any problems? What do you think?

Comment: usually a dash `_` is used to indicate a not used parameter.

Comment: Echoing what Nina said, but no, there is no "problem" in using an empty param versus `()` in arrow functions. The only thing to be aware of is if you are using that same name in a closure above. That's why the bare underscore is a good convention.

Comment: "in my opinion ... more intuitive" - but for those unfamiliar with this convention of yours, this will be [a wtf moment](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m). "This function declares parameter `f` and then doesn't use it in any way. Is there an error here? What is going on? Why would they do this?"

Comment: You can take a look at [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). [Here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrows--one-arg-parens) is the section you might be interested regarding the question. This won't cause any errors, but I totally agree with @Sergio

Comment: The problem is when you work in teams and nobody else knows why you are writing functions in an unconventional way.

Comment: Shoudn't `let foo = f =>` be `let foo = (f) =>`?

Comment: @Red: this syntax is valid too.

Comment: Ah, alright. Thanks for noting. Kinda wierd though, as I would expect the `()`.

Comment: @Red: this is the entire premise of the question, `() => ` vs `f => `

Comment: If you personally don't like arrow functions, don't use them. That JS doesn't have strict function call arity doesn't mean you should rely on this "feature". Besides, you gonna get trouble with your coworkers.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with ES6 or arrow functions.  `foo = () => {` vs `foo = _ => {` is exactly the same question as `function foo() {` vs `function foo(_) {`.

Answer (score 2):

The function will have a different [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), so if any introspective code is using that property for anything, you may see unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As far as I was expecting that it might be a problem while working in teams i was looking for more technical issues like this one.